# SSRS localization implemented in DB

Tags: reporting-services, localization

I'm implementing some SSRS reports. The reports are required to be localized but the localization must be implemented in the DB and not in a referenced assembly.

My idea is to define one or more tables holding the localized data and to retrieve values by means of a function (parameters: tag and language). The retrieved value will be inserted in the report on the appropriate place.

But since every report has a set of strings to be localized I expect that this will impact the performance. Also some strings appear in more than one report so it would be good if the retrieved value is cached.

Can you give me an idea how the localization in the DB could be implemented in a good manner.

Comment: What are you localising? Labels on the report, or data in the tables?

Comment: I'm localizing only labels and titles.All the data I get from the DB is numbers and names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it this way:

- Implement a stored procedure getting as parameter language and report name. All the texts for the specified report are queried at once.
- In the SSRS report, add a dataset holding the retrieved data with the localization strings. This are all the texts for the current report. The data set contains two columns: key and test
- Every string to be localized is retrieved as expression:

  =Lookup("TagString", Fields!Key.Value, Fields!Text.Value, "DataSetWithLocalizedStrings")